# my django server is stopping without an error appearing

Tags: python, django

My Django server is stopping without an error appearing, I am making an application that captures the microphone and transcribes and translates everything that is said using the Google speech-to-text and Google translate APIs and I want to display the output of the API on a web page.

I'm having difficulty displaying the return from my api on the django server I tried with ajax and it didn't work I need it to update each sentence simultaneously

this is the python code of the application

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import speech_recognition as sr
from googletrans import Translator
import threading
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

translation_running = False

def paginaInicial(request):
    global translation_running

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if translation_running:
            translation_running = False
        else:
            translation_running = True
            translation_thread = threading.Thread(target=perform_translation)
            translation_thread.start()

    return render(request, "index.html")

def perform_translation():
    global translation_running

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.Microphone()

    while translation_running:
        with mic as source:
            print("Diga algo...")
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            audio = r.listen(source)

        try:
            audio_text = r.recognize_google_cloud(audio, credentials_json='', language='pt-BR')
            print("Texto transcrito:", audio_text)

            translation_result = translate_text(audio_text)

            if translation_running:
                logger.info(f'Texto Original: {audio_text}')
                logger.info(f'Texto Traduzido em Inglês: {translation_result["translated_text_en"]}')
                logger.info(f'Texto Traduzido em Espanhol: {translation_result["translated_text_es"]}')
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Não foi possível transcrever o áudio.")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("Erro na requisição à API: {0}".format(e))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Erro na tradução: {0}".format(e))
            # Registre o erro
            logger.error(f"Ocorreu um erro: {str(e)}")

def translate_text(audio_text):
    translator = Translator(service_urls=['translate.google.com'])

    result_en = translator.translate(audio_text, dest='en')
    translated_text_en = result_en.text
    print("Texto traduzido para inglês:", translated_text_en)

    result_es = translator.translate(audio_text, dest='es')
    translated_text_es = result_es.text
    print("Texto traduzido para espanhol:", translated_text_es)

    return {
        'translated_text_en': translated_text_en,
        'translated_text_es': translated_text_es
    }
```

This is the HTML that displays the translated spoken sentences. I don't know if the ajax is working because I can't test it.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{% static 'styles.css' %}" media="screen" />
    <title>Transcrição e Tradução de Áudio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Transcrição e Tradução de Áudio</h1>
    
    <form method="post" id="translationForm">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" id="translationButton">Iniciar Transcrição e Tradução</button>
    </form>
    
    
    
    <h1>{{ original_text }}</h1>
    
    
    <h1>{{ translated_text_en }}</h1>
    
    
    <h1>{{ translated_text_es }}</h1>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            let translateRunning = false;
            let translationInterval;
            let form =$('#translationForm');
            let translationButton =$('#translationButton');

            translationButton.click (function(){
                if (!translateRunning){
                    translateRunning = true;
                    form.submit();
                    translationButton.text("Parar Tradução");
                }
                else {
                    translateRunning = false;
                    clearInterval(translationInterval);
                    translationButton.text("Iniciar Tradução");
                }
            });
            form.on('submit', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{% url 'pagina-Inicial' %}",
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    timeout: 15000,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#original_text').text(data.original_text);
                        $('#translated_text_en').text(data.translated_text_en);
                        $('#translated_text_es').text(data.translated_text_es);

                        if(translateRunning) {
                            translationInterval = setInterval (function(){
                                form.submit();
                            }, 5000);//Tempo da frase 5 segundos 
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        console.log("Erro na solicitação AJAX");
                    }
                })
            });     
        });
    </script>
        
    
<!--
    {% if error_message %}
    <p><strong>Erro:</strong> {{ error_message }}</p>
    {% endif %}
-->
</body>
</html>
```